# how to access go templated kubernetes secret in manifest

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm running this tutorial https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html and found that the elasticsearch operator comes included with a pre-defined secret which is accessed through `kubectl get secret quickstart-es-elastic-user -o go-template='{{.data.elastic | base64decode}}'`. I was wondering how I can access it in a manifest file for a pod that will make use of this as an env var.  The pod's manifest is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user
          image: reactor/user
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "3000"
            - name: ES_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: quickstart-es-elastic-user
                  key: { { .data.elastic } }

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: user
  ports:
    - name: user
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

When trying to define `ES_SECRET` as I did in this manifest, I get this error message: `invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{\".data.elastic\":interface {}(nil)}\n`. Any help on resolving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret returned via API (`kubectl get secret ...`) is a JSON-structure, where there:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "elastic": "base64 encoded string"
  }
}
```

So you just need to replace

```yaml
key: { { .data.elastic } }
```

with

```yaml
key: elastic
```

since it's `secretKeyRef`erence (e.g. you refer a value in some `key` in `data` (=contents) of some secret, which name you specified above). No need to worry about base64 decoding; Kubernetes does it for you.

Comment: hello. I was having trouble with other stuff so wasn't able to fully test this. Now that I got those other issues sorted, I'm seeing this error: `{...caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Illegal base64 character
3a"},"header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer
realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}`. I was wondering how I might be able to decode this, since it seems like I may need to do that. Thank you!

Comment: @reactor It's hard to tell with so few details. AFAIK hex `3a` is a colon `:` character, which in terms of WWW-Authentication usually separate username and password. This is legit for `Basic` authentication type, not sure if it's allowed for `ApiKey`. The guide you mentioned used `curl -u "elastic:$PASSWORD"` which is `Basic` authentication type.